# Wordpress php.ini file to set upload_max_filesize to get around 2MB upload

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I bought a template 2.2M and the limit on wordpress is set to 2M.

I am hosting the server so I have full access to files.

1. I have created a info.php and found:
   Loaded configuration file: none
2. Then setting php.ini is not working:
   php.ini // and php5.ini
   upload_max_filesize = 32M
   post_max_size = 32M
3. Also tried to set:
   wp-config.php
   define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
4. Also tried:
   No .htaccess file

   - php_value post_max_size 30M
   - php_value upload_max_filesize 30M

I anded with coping the file to the server, but I am curious;
It must be possible, right?

Answer (score 5):

If your hosting allows you to upload a custom **php.ini** file, just create it at **/wp-admin** folder.

```
upload_max_filesize=280M ;Max file size
max_execution_time=600 ; Script's max execution time, if it's short the file won't upload
memory_limit=1024M ; Memory limit, mine is high because i execute some script when uploading
post_max_size=280M ;Max POST size, it should be the same size as the file size limit
```

Then at wp-config add:

```
define(’WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ’64M’);
```

I've tested this in multiple servers, if it doesn't work is because your hosting blocks this directives.

Comment: Thank you very much, took all day fighting with this.  This works!  php.ini file, just create it at /wp-admin folder